# SSIS SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to export data from a SQL Server database to a MySQL instance, I've configured ADO.NET connection to the SQL Server and the MySQL Instance and both can connect fine, however when I try to import data into the the MySQL database table I am getting this error

> Error: 0xC020844B at Data Flow Task, ADO NET Destination [2]: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Unknown column 'p1' in 'field list'

There's no p1 column involved with the import and this is same error message I get when I try to export any of the 75 tables from the SQL Server instance to the MySQL instance, both instances are running on the same VM and I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I've googled the error message and found little in the way of help on this.

Comment: Check the actual Sql query code sent to MySQL.

Comment: How do I check that? not really used MYSQL in any anger before.

Comment: Enable General Log temporarily (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) and look in it.